# Is it possible to be at rest relative to the cosmic background radiation?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, reference-frames, time-dilation, cosmic-microwave-background

Could there be a body in the universe which is at rest relative to the cosmic background radiation? And how much slower would time elapse at this point relative to Earth?

The Milky Way is moving relative to the CMB at approx 2 million km per hour in the direction of the constellation Hydra. If that speed dropped to a very low number then I would consider that 'at rest' or very close to it.

I ask this question because I'd like to know if there are places in the universe with very low relative time dilations to us. It could be very efficient to locate computing power there.

Comment: To which precision do you want to be at rest, and how much delta-v are you willing to spend?

Comment: It's not very clear what you mean by "at rest" with respect to the CMB. If you mean at rest with respect to the radiation itself, well, that's not possible. If you mean in a reference frame such that the CMB looks homogeneous, we're already in that reference frame (to an excellent approximation).

Comment: The Milky Way is moving relative to the CMB at approx 2 million km per hour in the direction of the constellation Hydra.  If that speed dropped to a very low number then I would consider that 'at rest' or very close to it.

Comment: Is it impossible to find it because of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle? If you can measure the CMB then you know a body's position in the universe, so you can never then know its exact velocity?

Comment: As an aside, the nature of the equation in [Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) makes the _uncertainty_ computably relevant only at atomic and sub-atomic scales. So, the macroscopic objects are essentially unaffected by this uncertainty. A tutorial such as [this](http://formulas.tutorvista.com/physics/heisenberg-uncertainty-principle-formula.html) would elaborate on the concept more lucidly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The frame in which the CMB is isotropic is just the rest frame of all the matter in the universe when we average out the [peculiar velocities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peculiar_velocity). The CMB is the black body radiation released by the matter (mostly ionised hydrogen) at the time of [recombination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recombination_(cosmology)) about 378,000 years after the Big Bang. So its distribution reflects the distribution of the matter at that time. The point is that the frame is defined by the averaged out motion of the matter, and the CMB serves as a convenient label for it - the frame isn't as it is because of the radiation, the radiation is as it is because of the matter.

So yes of course there will be some objects that have a peculiar velocity of zero and therefore are at rest in the frame shared by the CMB. We call these objects [comoving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comoving_distance#Comoving_coordinates). Most objects are not comoving because they have been accelerated by concentrations of mass in their vicinity, but assuming a random distribution of velocities there will be some objects that are comoving (to whatever precision you require).

As you say in a comment the Solar System happens not to be a comoving object, but in relativistic terms its peculiar velocity is not great. [According to NASA](https://image.gsfc.nasa.gov/poetry/ask/a10552.html) the peculiar velocity of the Solar System is about 360 km/sec, which is about $0.0012c$ and corresponds to a [Lorentz factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor) of about $1.0000007$. So our relative time dilation compared to an object with a peculiar velocity of zero is only a factor of $1.0000007$.